# Including Image in pdf using PDFKit in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, pdfkit

I have used PDFKit gem in rails and generated a Invoice.pdf file from HTML.
I am using PDFKit.new(html) and not middleware and it works.

In my view, I don't need any images to be included.But I need to add image/logo in the generated PDF file. Is it possible to include image in pdf alone? How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add to images which you want to display class such as .display_in_pdf, and in your stylesheet:

```
@media print {
 .display_in_pdf {
    display: block;
  }
}

.display_in_pdf { 
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I want to include image only in pdf and not in html page.